# How to remove words made up of same repetitive letters

Tags: python, regex, nlp

The dataframe column contains few words with repetitive letters. I want to remove words that are entirely made up of same letters from the dataframe column and keep the first occurrence of the letter in other cases where the letters repeat more than 2 times consecutively.
df-

```
id   text
1     aaaa
2     bb
3     wwwwwwww
4     Hellooooo
5     See youuuu
```

Output

```
id   text
1     
2     
3   
4    Hello
5    See you
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's good that you've clearly explained your problem and expected output, however, we ask that you demonstrate an attempt to write the code yourself first, and then we will help you to fix it up :)

Comment: Here's a simple regex that matches strings consisting entirely of the same character:  `^(.)\1*$`  To encode this as a python string, you would use `"^(.)\\1*$"` (note that the \ character is doubled to escape it).

Comment: @TomKarzes can you explain this in terms of dataframe syntax. I am not able to apply this to a dataframe column

Comment: You can try to find answer how to filter out dataframe rows (what dataframe implementation? Pandas?) based on predicate. As a predicate you can use that regexp.

Comment: @kolen yes pandas

Answer (score 0):

if you don't like regex same as me, you can go old school, it might be inefficient but you will get the idea

```
s = 'Seee youuuu sooooon'

def word_precess(s):
    c = ''
    flag = ''
    counter = 0
    for i, letter in enumerate(s):
        if letter == flag:
            counter += 1
            if counter > 2:
                continue  # start the loop from beginning
        else:
            flag = letter
            counter = 1
        c = c + letter

    return c

print(word_precess(s))
```

output>>>

```
See youu soon
```

note: the result has "Youu" with double "u" and is not "See You soon" simply because i couldn't make the script understand words meaning.